# Linearize with Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, mono, ienumerable

Is there a way to linearize a `IEumerable<IEumerable<a>>` in Linq (or an elegant solution).

I have a method who returns a `IEnumerable<b>`. I use the `Select` method on a method of `b` that produces an `IEnumerable<a>`, this results in a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<a>>`. Is there a way to concatenate these enumerable to a `IEnumerable<a>`-object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for `a.SelectMany(x => x)`
(or, in-context, `b.SelectMany(b => b.Something())`)

Comment: Is there also an inline equivalent? Like `IEnumerable<a> test = from b in B() where b.Value > 0 select b.ValueEnum;` but with SelectMany?

Comment: @CommuSoft: `from b in B() from a in b.Whatever() select thingy`